# Atomic in Akka 2.3.4

Tags: scala, akka, atomic

I am trying to use atomic in Akka, but I read in the docs that atomic is in version 1.3 and I'm using 2.3.4. I haven't been able to find anything in the docs of any version since then that will explain what happened to atomic.  Most of the results I get point me to Persistence in Akka, which i wasn't able to understand. Does anyone know what happened to atomic after version 1.3? Was it replaced by something else, or is there an equivalent in the current version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about `atomic` from Akka STM module - in Akka 2.x STM [was replaced](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/project/migration-guide-1.3.x-2.0.x.html#stm) with [scala-stm](http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/) library.

Akka transactors, which also have `atomic` method were [removed in 2.3 version](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/project/migration-guide-2.2.x-2.3.x.html).

Comment: Yes, sorry i realize that wasn't clear from my question. i was asking about atomic from stm. what version of scala is that because i didn't find that when i looked in the scala.concurrent package earlier. Also thank you for your help.

Comment: The problem is that the documentation for ScalaSTm still uses atomic, and that's the problem. My compiler says it can't find value atomic. And my compiler also says stm is not a member of package scala.concurrent. this is what i was concerned about in my comment above.

Comment: Maybe you didn't add scala-stm to project dependencies? See http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/quick_start.html for example

Comment: Yeah that's what it was. I should have been able to see that.